# How does one create a C function pointer from a Scheme function in Guile?

Tags: c, scheme, guile

I am trying to write a wrapper for a C library that contains a function which takes another function to achieve polymorphism (i.e. a generic function). I would like to write my wrapper such that it takes a Scheme function and passes it to the generic function as a C function pointer. Does Guile provide functionality that would allow me to turn a Scheme function into a C function pointer?

Comment: Can you post a code example in which you would like your function pointer to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `procedure->pointer` procedure which is described in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Dynamic-FFI.html#index-procedure_002d_003epointer).